# Error when trying example Autocad usage

Tags: python

My autocad object has created well but getting error on `acad.prompt()`. Following is the error:

```
acad.prompt("Hello")
Hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "c:\users\snehal\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-lipjer\pyautocad-0.2.0-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\pyautocad\api.py", line 162, in prompt
File "c:\users\snehal\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-lipjer\pyautocad-0.2.0-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\pyautocad\api.py", line 74, in doc
File "c:\users\snehal\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-lipjer\pyautocad-0.2.0-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\pyautocad\api.py", line 63, in app
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes-1.1.3-py2.7.egg\comtypes\client_init_.py", line 173, in GetActiveObject
clsid = comtypes.GUID.from_progid(progid)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes-1.1.3-py2.7.egg\comtypes\GUID.py", line 78, in from_progid
_CLSIDFromProgID(unicode(progid), byref(inst))
File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 950, in GetResult
WindowsError: [Error -2147221005] Invalid class string
```

Comment: Try to use [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyautocad/) example first.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.